# Spring boot logging setup of FileAppender - where does it use the max-size property?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, default, logback

Overflowers

Please pardon my question if it's answer it or the answer is naive.

I have a very basic Spring Boot (1.5.4) logging setup in application.properties:

```
logging.level.org=WARN
logging.level.com=WARN
logging.level.springfox=OFF
logging.level.org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast=ERROR
logging.level.com.MyCompany.kph=DEBUG
logging.file=/var/MyProduct/logs/MyProduct.log
logging.file.max-size=2GB
logging.file.max-history=100
```

The 2GB is not being honoured. No value I put in there is being honoured. Even xxxxx as a value does not cause a blow-up.

logging.file does - and I can see that being used inside DefaultLogbackConfiguration.

From my source-following I can see method DefaultLogbackConfiguration#setMaxFileSize(a, b) being called. But that method is fixed at 10MB. This aligns with the behaviour i'm seeing.

Am I doing something wrong and triggering the very default behaviour? Or Does default behavior get loaded first then specific stuff goes on top? (If it does, I can't find it and it's not working for me).

Can someone point to me where max-size gets consumed and used?

Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 0):

Christ just by writing this post and reading the docs for MY-SPRING-VERSION, I see max-size is not used at all. That is why it's not working.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.19.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging